# Click event inside of a Modal - test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Trying to run a test for the following code, but node can't be found .Using jest and enzyme for ReactJS

```
 render () {
return (
  this.state.permissionsLoaded ?
  this.state.localPermissions[globals.UI_DATASOURCEDESIGNER] ? 
  this.state.datasourcePermissionsLoaded ?
  this.state.allowCurrentDatasource ?
      <div>
       <Modal isOpen={this.state.addRequestModalOpen} style={shareModal}>
       <div title="Close Window Without Saving" className="sidemodal_addnew_x" onClick={() => {this.closeAddModal()}}><FontAwesome name='xbutton' className='fa-times' /></div>
```

Keep getting the following error: Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

Here is what I have so far for my test:

```
beforeEach(() => wrapper = mount(<MemoryRouter keyLength={0}><Datasource {...baseProps} /></MemoryRouter>));


 it("Test Click event on Add DataSource ", () => {
  wrapper.find('Datasource').setState({
   permissionsLoaded:true,
   localPermissions:true,
   datasourcePermissionsLoaded:true,
   allowCurrentDatasource:true,
   addRequestModalOpen:true

   })
  wrapper.update();
  wrapper.find('Datasource').find('.sidemodal_addnew_x').simulate('click')

 });
```

Here as list of my state:

```
permissionsLoaded: false,
datasourcePermissionsLoaded: false,
allowCurrentDatasource: false,
localPermissions:{
    [globals.UI_DATASOURCEDESIGNER]:false,
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it looks like you are trying to find a node which will be conditionally rendered if all of the state variables you've mentioned are true, which none of them are (you are actually setting them all to false and updating the wrapper beforehand). This means that there is no `.sidemodal_addnew_x` to be found that can be used to simulate a click on, hence why you get that error message.

In case you've wanted to test for the existence of that component instead, you can do the following:

```
expect(wrapper.find('Datasource').find('.sidemodal_addnew_x').exists()).to.equal(false);
```

If you do want to test the click make sure the component gets .sidemodal_addnew_x gets rendered by settings the state variables to true:

```
it("Test Click event on Close Window Without Saving", (done) => {
  baseProps.onClick.mockClear();
  wrapper.find('Datasource').setState({
    permissionsLoaded:true,
    localPermissions:true,
    datasourcePermissionsLoaded:true,
    allowCurrentDatasource:true,
    addRequestModalOpen:true,
    }, () => {
      wrapper.update();    
      wrapper.find('Datasource').find('.sidemodal_addnew_x').simulate('click');
      done();
    });
});
```

Comment: But how could i  test a click event for example ?

Comment: Existence of the component worked fine, onclick  did not. Couldn't find any node.

Comment: any reason why onclick can be found ?

Comment: @user9191 can u update the original post? Did you set the states to true?

Comment: updated. Still node cant be found. When i run console.log(wrapper.debug()) i dont see any modal content inside of it

Comment: @user9191 setState is async, maybe the state is not updated before you do the click. Could you try what's in my updated answer?

Comment: Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

Comment: @user9191 How about you remove the at(0) part, so like: `wrapper.find('Datasource').find('.sidemodal_addnew_x').simulate('click');`

Comment: did that already as well, i tried  the following too :  wrapper.find('Datasource').find('.sidemodal_addnew_x').props().onClick(); same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191854/discussion-between-etarhan-and-user-9191).